# .NET WebBrowser problem

Tags: .net, caching, browser

I am using the `WebBrowser` control to post some data to a web server. I did notice that this doesn't work all the time if the query is the same and I guess this is due to some caching configuration.

E.g. I did try to post with an extra parameter who's value is the current timestamp but that's not the solutions I want.

I also tried `new WebBrowser().Navigate("url here")`. This works all the time, but I would like to reuse objects.

The `Refresh()` method did seem to make it work some times, but I could not figure out its exact behavior.

So how could I make the `webBrowser.Navigate("url here")` always hit the server without tricks ? Or what to use instead ?

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest to add fake parameter to your target url,
for example add "&request10022"
It will not take data from cache.

Comment: That's what I was saying, but what's that ? :-) workarounds everywhere ! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Beside @TheNIK suggestion, as `WebBrowser` uses Internet explorer engine, so disabling IE cache also works as described [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=636387)